# How to load environment path during executing command via ssh?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I'm trying to run a script (let's call it `test.sh`) via ssh as follows

```
ssh ${user}@${ip} "python3 test.py"
```

and the test.py is as follows

```
import os

# Do sth
...
os.system("emulator xxx")
...
```

The android environemnt paths are exported in `~/.bashrc`, but the above cmd failed due to missing ${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}. I know it's because `ssh ${user}@{ip} cmd` will setup a non-login and non-interactive shell, but I wonder if there is any solution?

PS:
I have tried `#!/bin/bash --login` and it failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```bash
ssh -t ${user}@${ip} "bash -i -c 'python3 test.py'"
```